# An instance of NSFetchedResultsController requires a non-nil fetchRequest and managedObject Context in iOS 10

Tags: ios, swift, nsfetchedresultscontroller, ios10

The code worked well when I was using Xcode 7.3 with iOS 9 but when I migrated to Xcode 8  using swift 3, the code below shows me that runtime error. Still finding a solution for it

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController,NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate,UISearchResultsUpdating {
    var fetchResultController :NSFetchedResultsController<Restaurant>!
    var searchController : UISearchController!
    var searchResults :[Restaurant]  = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let fetchRequest : NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>  =  Restaurant.fetchRequest()
        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

        if let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.managedObjectContext{
            fetchResultController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest as! NSFetchRequest<Restaurant>, managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

            fetchResultController.delegate = self

            do{
                try fetchResultController.performFetch()
                restaurants = fetchResultController.fetchedObjects!
            }
            catch{
                print(error)
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's most unlikely that AppDelegate does not exist (otherwise the app won't launch) and the managedObjectContext in the Core Data template is non-optional anyway so the optional binding is not needed and you got your non-nil objects.

Comment: i removed that optional binding .still showing the same error

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see from the code below, you are getting a Restaurant object

```
var fetchResultController :NSFetchedResultsController<Restaurant>!
var searchController : UISearchController!
var searchResults :[Restaurant]  = []
```

But in your fetchRequest, you are defining it as an NSFetchRequestResult.

```
let fetchRequest : NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>  = Restaurant.fetchRequest()
```

It maybe an NSFetchRequestResult but I'd advice you to cast it directly as a restaurant. I had a similar issue and doing this worked. Try this, and see if it works.

```
let fetchRequest : NSFetchRequest<Restaurant>  = Restaurant.fetchRequest()
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

**-> Go to the App delegate**

Type this after the *last* curled brace:

```
let ad = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
let context = ad.persistenceContainer.viewContext
```

**-> Go back to the TableViewController**

Remove the `if let`.

**Type:**

```
var fetchResultController = NSFetchResultsController(
  fetchRequest: Your fetchRequest, 
  manageObjectContext: context (From the delegate), 
  sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil
)
self.fetchResultController = fetchResultController
```